# Подскажите готовые Widget-ы для построения графиков функций в Qt

Tags: qt

Подскажите готовые Widget-ы для построения графиков функций в Qt

Comment: QCustomPlot http://blog.harrix.org/?p=1813

Comment: Много их http://blog.harrix.org/?p=1837

Comment: Есть еще QWT, http://qwt.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть `QCustomPlot` http://qcustomplot.com и есть `QWT` http://qwt.sourceforge.net.
Субъективно, qcustomplot предлагает больше интерактивных возможностей, которые подробно описаны и реализованы в примерах